# How a Genius Sim can make money at home while having Fun?

Tags: the-sims-4

I'm a bit new to The Sims 4, and was wondering how my current Genius Sim, who has a job as a doctor, can most efficiently make some extra money at home and simultaneously have fun (raise the Fun meter). Is this even possible? I understand that he can paint or play music, but I was wondering if there's something else that he can do, which capitalizes on him being a Genius.

Think “Fun + Profit” please. So, for example, writing does not increase the Fun meter, and watching TV does not make money. And I may be looking at Fun+Profit home activities, if any, which benefit from the Focused moodlet, since the Genius trait affects how often a Sim becomes Focused.

Thanks for any tips and help.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not at home, but playing instruments in public can get you tips and increase your fun meter (the higher the skill with the instrument you plan to play, the more tips you will receive).

Comment: Thank you. I remember this from The Sims 3. Is it 3 that you're talking about? I ask 'cause I tagged my question with Sims 4, and I don't know if it works that way, too, in 4. =)

Comment: It still works that way in The Sims 4 too, which is very convenient.

Answer (score -1):

While I am not sure it does fun, as I have not done it on a Genius sim, hacking does get you money. You can do it on a computer, and then practice programming. Once you have high enough skill level for programming, you can hack. There are delays between hacking, however.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, nevermind, while it does make money it is not fun for a Genius sim.